# List ASCII text files

Tags: ascii

I want to list and sort all the files in a directory that are ASCII text files but don't necessarily have a .txt extension. How can I do this? I'm new to shell scripting.

Comment: Just to get it clear: you mean files do not *necessarily* have a `.txt` extension? (I assume they can have).

Comment: Exactly. And I want to print only the file names.

Comment: This sounds very much like homework. Hint: `file netflix-backtrace.txt` outputs `netflix-backtrace.txt: ASCII text`

Comment: I managed to list the files of type ASCII Text but it is something like "a.txt: ASCII Text". Is there any option to get only the file name? Without the "ASCII Text" part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `file` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in * # for every file in folder
do
  # if file reports "ASCII text"
  if file "$i" | grep --quiet 'ASCII text$'
  then
      # print filename
      echo "$i"
  fi
done
```

One liner:

```
$ for i in *; do if file "$i" | grep -q 'ASCII text$' ; then echo "$i"; fi; done
```